# How do I apply a hover selector on a child element when using BEM and Less?

Tags: html, css, less, bem

This is the first time that I am using BEM and less in the same project.

I am currently experiencing an issue with the `&:hover` and trying to target a child selector.

I get the gist of the way in which less works and I know why this doesn't work, but what I don't understand is how I would go about fixing it.

Currently I have the following

```
.sidebar {

    &__item {

        &:hover {
            background: rgba(0,0,0,.06);

            &-name {
                color: @primary;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So as you can see the issue is with the `&-name` selector.

The current structre for the DOM goes like this...

```
ul.sidebar
    li.sidebar__item
        a
        span.sidebar__item-name
```

When I hover over the `sidebar__item` I want to trigger a hover effect on both the item and the child.

Answer (score 0):

Add `&_item-name` with the `&__item`, So you would get the expected result!

```
  .sidebar {

    &__item {

      &-name {
        &:hover {
            background: rgba(0,0,0,.06);
        }
      }

    }
}
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: this seems good, but the only thing with this is would is affect the way in which the hover works currently and the background will get applied to the `__item-name` as well? I want to only apply a color change on hover with the `__item-name`

Comment: or you meant `&__item:hover &__item-name { background: #ccc }` ?!

Answer (score 0):

[sass interpolation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation)

maybe it can help you

```
.sidebar {    
    &__item {
        $item: &;
        &:hover {
            background: rgba(0,0,0,.06);
            #{$item}-name {
                color: @primary;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this option may also fit

```
.sidebar {    
    &__item {
        &:hover & {
            background: rgba(0,0,0,.06);
            &-name {
                color: @primary;
            }
        }
    }
}
```